# Regex in PHP not working

Tags: php, regex

My regex is:

`$regex = '/(?<=Α: )(([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))/';`

My content among others is:

```
Q: Email Address 
A: name@example.com
```

Rad Software Regular Expression Designer says that it should work.

Various online sites return the correct results.

If I remove the (?<=Α: ) lookbehind the regex returns all emails correctly.

When I run it from php it returns no matches.

What's going on?

I've also used the specific type of regex (ie (?<=Email: ) with different content. It works just fine in that case.

Comment: Which functions are you using to parse the regex? preg_*, eregi_*?

Comment: @phpisuber01 preg_match().

Comment: The `A` in your regular expression has some kind of diacritical on it,  the `A` in the content is a normal letter.

Comment: @Barmar The diacritical doesn't display in my browsers... it looks like an `A` character.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ It's not actually a diacritical. When I look at the letters side by side, this one is just taller. When I paste it into Emacs, it says it has code #x51371.

Comment: @Barmar Good to know. I should really stop using Windows for coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your regular expression contains `Α`, which has an accent over it, but the content contains `A`, which doesn't. So the lookbehind doesn't match.

I change the regex to:

```
$regex = '/(?<=A: )(([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))/';
```

and it works.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me....
An hour spent trying to find out what's wrong and in the end I'm looking for a Greek 'A' when I want an English one...

Answer (score 1):

This is my newer monster script for verifying whether an e-mail "validates" or not. You can feed it strange things and break it, but in production this handles 99.99999999% of the problems I've encountered. A lot more false positives really from typos.

```
<?php

$pattern = '!^[^@\s]+@[^.@\s]+\.[^@\s]+$!';

$examples = array(
  'email@email.com',
  'my.email@email.com',
  'e.mail.more@email.co.uk',
  'bad.email@..email.com',
  'bad.email@google',
  '@google.com',
  'my@email@my.com',
  'my email@my.com',
);


foreach($examples as $test_mail){
    if(preg_match($pattern,$test_mail)){
      echo ("$test_mail - passes\n");   
    } else {
      echo ("$test_mail - fails\n");                
    }
}

?>
```

**Output**

1. email@email.com - passes
2. my.email@email.com - passes
3. e.mail.more@email.co.uk - passes
4. bad.email@..email.com - fails
5. bad.email@google - fails
6. @google.com - fails
7. my@email@my.com - fails
8. my email@my.com - fails

Unless there's a reason for the look-behind, you can match all of the emails in the string with preg_match_all(). Since you're working with a string, you would slightly modify the regex slightly:

```
$string_only_pattern = '!\s([^@\s]+@[^.@\s]+\.[^@\s]+)\s!s';

$mystring = '
email@email.com - passes
my.email@email.com - passes
e.mail.more@email.co.uk - passes
bad.email@..email.com - fails
bad.email@google - fails
@google.com - fails
my@email@my.com - fails
my email@my.com - fails
';

preg_match_all($string_only_pattern,$mystring,$matches);

print_r ($matches[1]);
```

**Output from string only**

```
Array
(
    [0] => email@email.com
    [1] => my.email@email.com
    [2] => e.mail.more@email.co.uk
    [3] => email@my.com
)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question, which is about the `A:` lookbehind?

Comment: @Barmar I was getting to it. Sorry for the delay... I only write 160wpm.

Answer (score 1):

You are not most likely not using DOTALL flag `s` here which will make DOT match newlines as well in your regex:

```
$str = <<< EOF
Q: Email Address 
A: name@example.com
EOF;
if (preg_match_all('/(?<=A: )(([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))/s', 
                   $str, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name@example.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => name@example.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => example.
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of your regex issue itself, you should really consider not trying to write your own e-mail address regex parser.  See stackoverflow post: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) on why -- upshot: the RFC is long and demanding on your regex abilities.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the monster of a regex needed to correctly extract RFC email addresses!

Answer (score 0):

The A char in your subject is the "normal" char with the code 65 (unicode or ascii). But The A you use in the lookbehind of your pattern have the code 913 (unicode). They look similar but are different.